# Singleton Class provoke ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, singleton

I am using a singleton `Class` , extending `android.app.Application` declared like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application { 
  // my code ...
}
```

I my `Activity`, I create an instance of this class:

```
MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) getApplication();
```

This line of code is provoking a `java.lang.ClassCastException` .

Thank you for your help.

This my Logcat trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.core.MyApplication
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `MyApplication` in your manifest so the framework instantiates it as your application class.

For example,

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication">

    <!-- activities -->

</application>
```

Comment: I accept it in few seconds , thanks , I forget it ... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your `MyApplication` class in `manifest.xml` like

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 ....
 .....
</application>
```